# What does "from when" mean?

Tags: grammar

[Source Novel](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1935744828)

Oh, I knew. She was all alone with Vanja during the day, **from when** I went to my office until I returned, she felt lonely, and she had been looking forward so much to these two weeks. Some quiet days with her little family gathered round her, that was what she had been looking forward to. I, for my part, never looked forward to anything except the moment the office door closed behind me and I was alone and able to write.

Does this mean "she was alone with Vanja from the time I went..."? "Once I got out to the office, she was alone?"

Answer (score 3):

In this context, "from when" marks the beginning of the time period being referenced - so, starting at the time when the person left their office. The time period referenced ends at "until I returned".

Put more explicitly:

"Referring to the time between the moment when I left my office until the moment when I returned, she felt lonely."

Answer (score 1):

It simply means *from the time*.

Answer (score 0):

I find this a very ambiguous sentence.

The timeframe reference is clearly "from when I went to my office until I returned", but whether during this time she:

- (a) was all alone with Vanja
- (b) felt lonely
- (c) both (a) and (b)

I can't tell. It reminds me of the old actors' adage: "What's that on the road ahead"